# C strings and pointers

Tags: c, string, pointers

When declaring a string in C what is the difference between

```
char* mystring;
```

and

```
char *mystring;
```

Comment: The difference is where space is. You can also use `char*mystring;`

Comment: I think this is just code style difference

Comment: AFAIK char *mystring is more preferred...for obvious reasons...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is no difference. The second option is commonly preferred because it makes it easier to avoid this pitfall:

```
char* str1, str2;
```

Here, `str1` is a `char*` **but** `str2` is a plain `char`. The other way of writing the declaration makes it easier to see that you have to put an extra asterisk in there:

```
char *str1, *str2;
```

Now both variables are of type `char*`.

Comment: its preferable to split up such declarations on multiple lines due to initialization.

Answer (score 1):

No difference here. But those two below **are** different:

```
char *p1, *p2;
```

and

```
char* p1, p2;
```