# Different of the Asterisk * in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, ios4

Currently, I'm starting an iphone application development. So, I have to retrieve my C knowledge back ( which wasn't good, got **F** twice back at the collage )

After I went to several tutorials and books, I notice something,

```
1. MyClass* myInstance
2. MyClass *myInstance
3. (MyClass *)myInstance
```

So far as I know, all of those are pointer (If I'm not misunderstanding). But what is the different between each of them. Or, they are just the same but define in different ways.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9393699/c-strings-and-pointers

Comment: possible duplicate of [Placement of the asterisk in Objective-C](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1105815/placement-of-the-asterisk-in-objective-c)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**1**, **2** no difference - depends on which style you prefer.

**3** could be either a method declaration or the syntax for casting (thanks rob mayoff).

Method declaration: https://stackoverflow.com/a/683290/187954

Casting: https://stackoverflow.com/a/690760/187954

Comment: #3 is also the syntax for casting.

Comment: Thanks for the 1 and 2 clarification. But, does the 3rd one which is an input for a method are also mean it is a pointer too?

Comment: Yes, it's a pointer.  Objective-C objects are always passed by explicit reference (meaning, using a pointer), never by value.

Comment: What about a sample method declaration in a link that you provided. "- (void) setPersonName: (char *)name andAge:(int)age andHeight:(float)height" .... name is definitely a pointer, what about age and height?

Comment: They are not objects - they are primitive types.